# How to update redux state from rtk query?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, rtk-query

Why does redux State only update upon logging out and in, and not when the second api call is called from fetchBaseQueryReAuth?

The second api call is successful upon the second attempt after the first one fails, but reduxState does not update state in real time, it is only updated when I log back in again?

Here is my apiSlice:

```
export const apiSlice = createApi({
    baseQuery: baseQueryWithReauth,
    endpoints: builder => ({
        saveProduct: builder.mutation({
            query: (productId) => ({
              url: `http://localhost:3005/product/${productId}/save`,
              method: 'PUT',
            }),
            transformResponse : (response) => {
                const data = response
                console.log(data); // log the response data
                return data;
            }
        })
    })
});
```

The state is updated normally when the first api call works, but I still can't wrap my head around why it's not updated after the second api call is called and does successfully update my mongodb and reduxState behind the scenes?

Here is the dispatch action I use when the first api call works :

```
dispatch(saveProduct(response.data.productId));
```

Here is the handler on the client triggers the api calls and updates reduxState :

```
const [saveProduct, { isLoading,  data }] = useSaveProductMutation();



const handleSaveProduct = (productId) => {
  saveProduct(productId).unwrap().then((data) => {
    // Handle successful response
    console.log(data)
  }).catch((error) => {
    // Handle error
  })
}

const savedProductHandler = () => {
  if (reduxUser && reduxUser.savedProducts.includes(productId)) {
    dispatch(unSaveProductAction(productId));
  } else {
    dispatch(saveProductAction(productId)); 
    handleSaveProduct(productId);
  }
}
```

To give more context, the Save button is supposed to switch to Unsave when a product is successfully saved and redux state is updated correctly when the first api calls works.

However, if the first api call fails, and the second one is called successfully, redux state does not update as a logged in user, only until I log out and back in again. The save button does not switch to UnSave and when I click Save again, it shows an error that Product is already saved.
Here is the client code responsible for this :

```
 {reduxUser && isLoggedIn && reduxUser.savedProducts.includes(productId) ? (
  <Button bg="green" color="white" onClick={savedProductHandler}>Unsave</Button>
) : (
  <Button bg="green" color="white" onClick={savedProductHandler}>Save</Button>
)}
```

I've tried fixing this by dispatching the data from useSaveProductMutation() on the front end, however the redux state still does not update, only until I log out and back in again. Which then, shows me the product saved from the second successful api call.

Also I have tried using extraReducers to update state, but still no success on seeing it update as a logged in user. The state continues to update only when I'm logged out and back in.

```
export const apiSlice = createApi({
    baseQuery: baseQueryWithReauth,
    endpoints: builder => ({
        saveProduct: builder.mutation({
            query: (productId) => ({
              url: `http://localhost:3005/product/${productId}/save`,
              method: 'PUT',
            }),
            transformResponse : (response) => {
                const data = response.productId
                console.log(data); // log the response data
                return data;
            },
            extraReducers: builder => {
                builder.addCase(saveProduct.fulfilled,  (state, action) => {
                    // Update the auth state with the saved product data
                    console.log('reducer is working')
                    const savedProduct = action.payload;
                    state.auth.user.savedProducts.push(savedProduct);
                  });
            }
        }),
    })
});
```

I have also tried extraReducers like this and it hasn't worked.

```
const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState: {
    user: null,
    token: null,
    refreshToken: null, // add new refreshToken state property
    products: [],
    savedProducts: [],
},
reducers: {
saveProduct(state,action) {
      const savedProduct = action.payload;
      state.user.savedProducts.push(savedProduct);
    },
},
 extraReducers: (builder) => {
      builder
        .addCase(addProduct.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
          const newProduct = action.payload;
          state.products.push(newProduct);
        })
        .addCase(apiSlice.endpoints.saveProduct.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
          const savedProduct = action.payload;
          state.user.savedProducts.push(savedProduct);
        })
    },
```

The problem with me having to log out and in again in order to see my savedProduct is my baseQueryWithReauth function. What I'm doing wrong is setting the token state and user state of my auth slice to be the newAccessToken retrieved from my server along with the userId to sign the newAccessToken.

What ends up happening is that when setUser and setToken are run, a new user is created instead of being updated. I know this because my Avatar image is blank and, when state.auth.user is console logged, it's only the string of userId that was set from baseQueryWithReauth instead of being all of the different states of authSlice as it shows when I log in. Also, when I console logged state.auth.user.savedProducts, after setting user and token in the baseQueryWithReauth, it was undefined.

Also, I know this because setUser and setToken are dispatched when I log in as a user.

When the second api call is run successfully, state.auth.user.savedProducts is updated behind the scenes and is only updated when I log in again.

How can I adjust my baseQueryWithReAuth so that state.auth.token and/or state.auth.user is updated to my authSlice when logged in?
Or would writing an updateToken or updateUser reducer function solve this problem?

For context, here is the baseQueryWithReauth:

```
const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3005',
    credentials: 'include',
    prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
        const token = getState().auth.token
        console.log(token)
        if (token) {
            headers.set("Authorization", `Bearer ${token}`)
        }
        return headers
    }
})

const baseQueryWithReauth = async (args, api, extraOptions) => {
    let result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions)
    console.log(result);
    if (result?.error?.originalStatus === 403) {
        console.log('sending refresh token')
        // send refresh token to get new access token 
        const refreshResult = await baseQuery('/refresh-token', api, extraOptions)
        if (refreshResult?.data) {
            console.log(refreshResult);
            const token = refreshResult.data.token 
            const user = refreshResult.data.userId
            api.dispatch(setToken(token))
            api.dispatch(setUser(user))
            localStorage.setItem("accessToken", token)
            // retry the original query with new access token 
            result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions)
        } else {
            api.dispatch(logout())
        }
    }

    return result
}
```

Here is my authSlice:

```
const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth',
  initialState: {
    user: null,
    token: null,
    savedProducts: [],
},
reducers: {
    setToken(state, action) {
      state.token = action.payload;
},
setUser(state, action) {
      state.user = action.payload;
      console.log('userId set:', state.user);
},
saveProduct(state,action) {
      const savedProduct = action.payload;
      state.user.savedProducts.push(savedProduct);
    },
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should really not put additional logic into `transformResponse`. That function should be pure and there is no guarantee that RTK Query might not execute it 20 times in the future, or skip execution if the response was the same one as last time. It's unlikely, but you get my point: that function has a purpose, and side effects are not that purpose.

Side effects should go into the lifecycle events - in your case you can wait in [onQueryStarted](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi#onquerystarted) until the query has finished successfully, and then dispatch your action.

Comment: Thank you for that. Do you happen to know why redux state is not updated from the response.data from the second successful api call after the first one fails from baseQueryWithReAuth? Redux state is only updated when I log out and back in and have tried for hours to figure how to fix it. Any tips on where to look in the RTK Query Docs? I updated my post to show the problem. I've tried using onQueryStarted but I'm probably coding it wrong. I'll also update post to show that code.

Comment: I'd need to see an actual reproduction for that. Seeing your example above: you know that you can also do that in an `extraReducer` in your slice without ever dispatching an action at all? See [this example](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/examples#using-extrareducers)

Comment: I've tried that and unfortunately the same problem persists. I updated my post at the end to show how I used extraReducers, is this what you meant or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Then I would assume that you have a completely different problem - something inside the `baseQueryWithReAuth` you use seems to be broken.
If this is an implementation from the docs, could you open an issue with a runnable reproduction?

Comment: You were right that there is an issue with baseQueryWithReAuth. It's what's causing the problem. Before I do a runnable reproduction, please look at the updated code at the end. I included baseQueryWithReAuth with an explanation of the problem. Please look it over and let me know what you think on the best way to solve this.

Comment: Maybe you should do ` const user = refreshResult.data` there and not set the whole user to the `userId`?